# How to see asp.net webservice Request envelop

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am working on an asp.net application.I need to call php webservice.I am using asp.net WebReference method.It serialize my request.How to print my webservice request.

Comment: er...web services are based on the XML format... your question is not clear. More about webservices.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Comment: I need to my print my xml request that's all

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: If you were to use "Add Service Reference" (as you should, unless you're stuck with an old version of .NET), then you could get message logging, and see exactly what you are sending and receiving to the service.

Comment: But when I am using Add Service Reference it doesn't create model class for me..

Comment: Look in the "Output" window to see if you have an error. It should be creating all the classes you need. If it doesn't, then there is likely a problem with the service. In particular, many PHP services are not WS-I BP 1.1 compliant, and so do not interoperate well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the developer tools in Chrome, IE or Firefox to monitor network traffic.  Personally I use Chrome; Hit F12, then click the network tab.  See the attached picture:

[image: Screenshot]

Here is an example of a POST Payload.  (This is posting JSON data, but you should see what I mean)

[image]

Comment: Yes, it shows under the headers when its a post (Request Payload).  I will add an updated screenshot of a POST I just did on a project I am currently working on. (In this case its JSON data being posted, but you should get the idea.)